# Foreign key in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have created a table in oracle which has one FK that refers to 3 primary keys in 3 different table.But when I want to insert into it I see an error says parent key not found!what should I do?

```
CREATE TABLE A
(   X       char(11)        not null,
    id      char(11)        not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(X,id),
    FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES B(employee_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES C(customer_id)   
);
```

Comment: did you insert data in you table B and C matching your `id` value in table A?

Comment: Something looks wrong with the design. One field of a table referring to three different tables mandating the existence of same value across three tables as primary key.

Comment: Cybernate is right. It doesn't make sense to try and have one foreign key to pkey values in two different tables. I'm surprised Oracle would even allow these constraints to be created.

Comment: yes ,I did.I will do the way Justin told in his answer,Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a single parent table (for the sake of example I'll call it Party). Reference the Party table from all three tables A,B,C. As a result, the multiple foreign keys would be replaced by one foreign key referencing the Party table. This is an example of a generalisation / specialisation, "subtype" pattern which you will find in many data modelling books.

Answer (score 3):

Your column `id` in table A refers to a column in table B and also a column in table C. If you need to insert data in table A, the value in the `id` field must match a value in table B **and** C, otherwise you are breaking your FK constraint; it is impossible to insert a row in table A that contains a column refering to an *unexisting* row in table B or C.

Answer (score 3):

If your intention is that the `ID` column in A is **either** a foreign key to the `EMPLOYEE_ID` column in B **or** a foreign key to the `CUSTOMER_ID` column in C, you've got a problem-- you can't declare a foreign key for this either/or type relationship.

From a data modeling standpoint, you have a few options

- You can create two columns in A, an `EMPLOYEE_ID` column that is a nullable foreign key to the `EMPLOYEE_ID` column in B and a `CUSTOMER_ID` column that is a nullable foreign key to the `CUSTOMER_ID` column in C.  You can then create a check constraint on A that exactly one of these two columns is NULL.
- You can create a new `ENTITY` table that has all `EMPLOYEE_ID` and `CUSTOMER_ID` values.  `EMPLOYEE_ID` in B would be a foreign key to the `ENTITY_ID` column in `ENTITY` as would the `CUSTOMER_ID` column in C and the `ENTITY_ID` column in A.
- You can leave the columns in A alone and eliminate the foreign key.  Then you would be responsible for verifying referential integrity in your code.  This last option is generally not a good idea.

Generally, I'd also be **really** suspicious of columns declared as CHAR(11).  There is virtually no case in Oracle where it really makes sense to use CHAR rather than VARCHAR2.  At best, it's a wash.

Comment: i'd opt for the second option, personally.

Comment: But if I write as you say I cant say in check that 2 other be null since all of them are primary keys.You know what I mean?

Comment: A primary key, whether composite or not, cannot contain nulls. By definition keys don't permit nulls. Oracle doesn't permit nulls in columns subject to a PRIMARY KEY constraint.

Comment: @Dportas - You're absolutely right.  I was confusing the semantics for composite unique constraints with composite primary key constraints.  For clarity, I'll delete that comment.  Thanks for the correction!